# vuetifyのselectboxの値によってフォームの表示，非表示を切り替えたい

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

## 概要

vue + vuex + vuetify を用いて動的なフォームを作成したいのですが，
selectboxで選ばれた結果によって動的にフォームの表示，非表示を切り替えたいです．

## 環境

vue 2.5.2
vuex 3.0.1
vuetify 0.17.2

## 現状

App.vue

```
<template>
<v-app>
　<v-form>
  　<template v-for="form in forms">
    　<v-text-field
      v-if="form.type==='text' && form.show"　<!-- form.showがtrueのとき表示-->
      :label="form.label"
      v-model="form.value"
      required
      >
      </v-text-field>
      <v-select
      v-if="form.type==='select'"
      :label="form.label"
      v-model="form.value"
      :items="form.options"
      @change="change"
      required
      >
      </v-select>
     </template>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'forms',
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    change () {
      //ここどうすればよいのかわからない．
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

form.js(vuexのモジュール)

```
const state = {
  forms: [
    {
      id: 'name',
      label: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      show: true
    },
    {
      id: 'sex',
      label: 'sex',
      type: 'select',
      options: [
        'man',
        'woman'
      ],
      value: '', //ここのvalueが変化したタイミングでquestionのshowを書き換えたい
      effect: [ //影響を与えるフォームのid.このidのshowを変更したい
        'questionForMan',
        'questionForWoman'
      ],
      show: true
    },
    {
      id: 'questionForMan',
      label: 'question',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      show: false //sexによって質問を
    },
    {
      id: 'questionForWoman',
      label: 'question',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      show: false
    }
  ]
}

const getters = {
  forms (state) {
    return state.forms
  }
}

const mutations = {

}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
}
```

## 質問

App.vueの`<v-select>`が変化したタイミングで`forms`の中の`questionForMan`,`questionForWoman`の中の値`show`を変えることでフォーム表示，非表示を行いたいです．

`forms`の中のデータはaxiosで取得する予定なので，実行時にオブジェクトを取ってくるしか無いのですが，
`v-model`で値を変えてもその後のstateの変化をどう処理すればよいかわかりません．

また，`@change="処理"`でメソッドを呼び出すことも考えたのですが，vuetifyの`<v-select>`が現在何の値を取っているのか（`e.target.value`等で取得できるのか？）,`mutations`の呼び出し方がわかりません．

vue, vuetify, vuexを触るのは初めてで初歩的な質問なのかもしれませんが，どなたかご教授ください．